# What's the classification of iterative, suggest/response, deductive games like Mastermind or Battleship?

Tags: game-theory

I've read a bit about the various ways of categorizing games (symmetric, cooperative, zero-sum, etc), but I haven't figured out the proper way to classify games with the following characteristics:

- A secret (sometimes ordered) set of game-pieces is selected from a larger, finite set of pieces.
- The composition of the secret set *does not change* during the game.
- The "guesser" makes a series of suggestions about either some or all of the set.
- Guesser is given feedback about their suggestion being either: entirely correct, partially correct, or entirely incorrect.
- First-order logic can deduce the composition of the secret set *once enough information exists*, but the real skill in the game lies in knowing which guesses to make in order to maximize the information learned per guess.
- "Success" in the game is generally measured by how few suggestions need to be made.
- Making a poor/incorrect guess does *not* end the game (for this reason, a game like Minesweeper doesn't really qualify); it just increases the number of guesses needs and, thereby, lowers the player's score.

Off the top of my head, I know of a few games which (although, on the surface, seeming very different) all fall into this classification:

- Mastermind
- Battleship (actually two instances of this game happening in either direction)
- Clue

Does anybody know of many others?